# Excel Macro - Decision making over lookup source

Tags: excel, vba

Still not very good with VBA, trying to learn. Question is whether I should create a user form with TypeArray items, ask them which items go to which "Port Summary" header, then create a new TypeArray, or just try to make the program reconfigure itself somehow (and - how?)?

I've got this data from a substantial number of CSV files (this is a snippet, the actual contains 60 - 250 rows, and 5 or more "Marker" columns) - let's call this Range1:

```
╔════════════════════════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════╦══════════════════╦══════════════╗
║         CSV File Name          ║ Marker 1 ft/freq ║ Marker 1 dBm ║ Marker 2 ft/freq ║ Marker 2 dBm ║ Marker 3 ft/freq ║ Marker 3 dBm ║
╠════════════════════════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════╬══════════════════╬══════════════╣
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_DTFL.csv  ║ 113.82           ║ (42.88)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_DTFS.csv  ║ 113.82           ║ (43.96)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_DTFWS.csv ║ 113.82           ║ (12.72)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_RLL.csv   ║ 824.04           ║ (31.87)      ║ 848.97           ║ (34.09)      ║ 869.04           ║ (30.19)      ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_RLS.csv   ║ 824.04           ║ (23.49)      ║ 848.97           ║ (22.61)      ║ 869.04           ║ (23.86)      ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_RLWS.csv  ║ 824.04           ║ (3.43)       ║ 848.97           ║ (3.44)       ║ 869.04           ║ (3.53)       ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1_DTFL.csv  ║ 113.82           ║ (42.88)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2_DTFS.csv  ║ 113.82           ║ (43.96)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2_DTFWS.csv ║ 113.82           ║ (12.72)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2_RLL.csv   ║ 824.04           ║ (31.87)      ║ 848.97           ║ (34.09)      ║ 869.04           ║ (30.19)      ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2_RLS.csv   ║ 824.04           ║ (23.49)      ║ 848.97           ║ (22.61)      ║ 869.04           ║ (23.86)      ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2_RLWS.csv  ║ 824.04           ║ (3.43)       ║ 848.97           ║ (3.44)       ║ 869.04           ║ (3.53)       ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_DTFL.csv   ║ 113.82           ║ (42.88)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_DTFS.csv   ║ 113.82           ║ (43.96)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_DTFWS.csv  ║ 113.82           ║ (12.72)      ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║ N/A              ║ N/A          ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_RLL.csv    ║ 824.04           ║ (31.87)      ║ 848.97           ║ (34.09)      ║ 869.04           ║ (30.19)      ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_RLS.csv    ║ 824.04           ║ (23.49)      ║ 848.97           ║ (22.61)      ║ 869.04           ║ (23.86)      ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1_RLWS.csv   ║ 824.04           ║ (3.43)       ║ 848.97           ║ (3.44)       ║ 869.04           ║ (3.53)       ║
╚════════════════════════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════╩══════════════════╩══════════════╝
```

I get the following Test Types from the end of the "CSV File Name" values and assign them to a "TypeArray". It's possible that there may be some variance in what the Test Types are called ("RLS" could be "RL Short", for example).:

```
╔══════╦══════╦═══════╦═════╦═════╦══════╗
║ DTFL ║ DTFS ║ DTFWS ║ RLL ║ RLS ║ RLWS ║
╚══════╩══════╩═══════╩═════╩═════╩══════╝
```

I also create a "PortArray" of unique ports (minus the "TypeArray" value and ".csv" - a "PortArray" (e.g. "TestSite_ALPHA_850_1", "TestSite_ALPHA_850_2", TestSite_Beta_850_1, etc - see image at bottom).

My question involves how to work out this next part: I need to summarize (Port Summary) the above data into something like the following - let's call this Range2:

```
╔══════════════════════╦══════════╦═════════╦═════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦═══════════╦════════╦════════╦═════════╗
║         Port         ║ DTFWS PK ║ DTFL PK ║ DTFS PK ║ RLL RX PK ║ RLL TX PK ║ RLS RX PK ║ RLS TX PK ║ RWS PK ║ RWS VY ║ RWS TTL ║
╠══════════════════════╬══════════╬═════════╬═════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬═══════════╬════════╬════════╬═════════╣
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_1 ║ (12.72)  ║ (42.88) ║ (43.96) ║ (34.09)   ║ (30.19)   ║ (22.61)   ║ (23.86)   ║ (3.44) ║ (3.53) ║ 3.49    ║
║ TestSite_ALPHA_850_2 ║ (12.78)  ║ (43.42) ║ (43.58) ║ (33.89)   ║ (29.33)   ║ (22.73)   ║ (23.45)   ║ (2.55) ║ (2.90) ║ 4.33    ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_1  ║ (12.51)  ║ (42.59) ║ (43.77) ║ (33.50)   ║ (29.67)   ║ (22.26)   ║ (23.12)   ║ (2.45) ║ (3.23) ║ 4.24    ║
║ TestSite_BETA_850_2  ║ (12.26)  ║ (42.74) ║ (43.50) ║ (33.68)   ║ (29.52)   ║ (21.81)   ║ (23.24)   ║ (3.29) ║ (2.95) ║ 3.79    ║
║ TestSite_GAMMA_850_1 ║ (12.06)  ║ (42.78) ║ (43.74) ║ (33.10)   ║ (29.61)   ║ (22.21)   ║ (23.13)   ║ (2.86) ║ (2.82) ║ 4.34    ║
║ TestSite_GAMMA_850_2 ║ (12.51)  ║ (42.79) ║ (43.79) ║ (33.11)   ║ (29.60)   ║ (22.59)   ║ (23.68)   ║ (3.10) ║ (3.37) ║ 3.90    ║
╚══════════════════════╩══════════╩═════════╩═════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩═══════════╩════════╩════════╩═════════╝
```

(Note: RWS Header corresponds to the RLWS Test Type in this example - the Range2 headings won't change much, but the Test Type value name might)

I use "TypeArray" with the (6) Test Types, and "PortArray" to fill out the Port Summary area, and I need to:

1. Cycle through each Port row in Range2
2. cycle through each column for each port (the Range2 header)
3. search the Range1 CSV File names for a match to PortArray &"_"&
   TypeArray
4. pull either (based on heading in Range2):

   - value of Marker 1 dbm column or
   - value of Marker 2 dbm column or
   - value of Marker 3 dbm column or
   - (value of Marker 2 dbm column + value of Marker 3 dbm column) divided by -2

I'm getting hung up on step 3, and don't know how to make sure my TypeArray is assigned to the right Port Summary heading (that they're not out of order - e.g. what if the File Names in Range1 aren't in alpha order? my TypeArray fills in top-down from that list and could be RLL, RLS, RLWS, DTFL, etc while my Range2 headers remain the same) **and** how do I use the same array item twice - i.e. use TypeArray item "RLL" to find Range2 heading item "RLL RX" and "RLL TX" before moving on to "RLS"?

Current example image:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XIILG.png)

I create Range2 using the following:

```
Function FillSummary()
Dim i As Integer
Dim lastrow As Integer
Dim rowSrc As Integer, colSrc As Integer 'These variables hold the row/column number for getting data
    rowSrc = 1
    colSrc = 1
Dim rowDest As Integer, colDest As Integer ' These variables hold the row/column number for data entry
    colDest = 1
Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range 'These variables hold where the info is copied from/pasted to
'=======================
Dim tmpPort As String, tmpSweep As String, trimPort As String, trimSweep As String
Dim portArr() As String
Dim sweepArr() As String
Dim swpHeadArr() As Variant
    swpHeadArr() = Array("DTFWS PK", "DTFL PK", "DTFS PK", "RLL RX PK", "RLL TX PK", _
        "RLS RX PK", "RLS TX PK", "RWS PK", "RWS VY", "RWS TTL")
'=========================================================

    'Find the last row of sweep data ======================
    With ActiveSheet 'find and set the location of the last row of sweep files
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
    End With
    Set rngSrc = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)) 'Set the range for our source to include all sweep files
    rowDest = lastrow + 2 'make our "rowSrc" variable one down from the last row of data
    '======================================================
    'Fill out the fields for our header info
    Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = "Port"
    For i = LBound(swpHeadArr) To UBound(swpHeadArr)
        colDest = colDest + 1 'increment column for sweep headers
        Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = swpHeadArr(i) 'input the sweep header value
    Next  'increment next array item and loop
    '===================
    'Format the header row
    Set rngDest = Range(Cells(rowDest, 1), Cells(rowDest, colDest))
        With rngDest
            .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
            .Font.Bold = True
            .Font.Size = 12
            .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
            .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
        End With
        '===============
        'Ensure the colum widths for sweeps are "11" (readable)
        Set rngDest = Range(Cells(rowDest, 3), Cells(rowDest, colDest))
        With rngDest
            .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11
        End With

    '======================================================
    'Start populating the arrays with each line/port & sweep type so it can be entered below
    For Each cell In rngSrc
        If Right(cell, 4) = ".csv" Then 'if the cell contains sweep data identified by ".csv" file type
            trimPort = Left(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_") - 1) 'will cut off sweep type & "_" before it
            trimSweep = Mid(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_") + 1, InStr(cell, ".csv") - 1 _
                - Len(Left(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_")))) 'will cut out everything but the sweep type
            ' ^^^^^^^^^^
            ' basically, take the middle of the cell starting at the last "_",
            ' for a length equal to position in the cell of ".csv", minus 1, minus
            ' the length of the cell contents to the point of the last "_"
            '===========
                'If (cell <> "") And (InStr(temp, cell) = 0) Then 'empty cell error handling
                If (InStr(tmpPort, trimPort) = 0) Then 'if the stuff we trimmed above doesn't equal our temp string
                  tmpPort = tmpPort & trimPort & "|" 'then add that stuff to our temp string with a delimiter
                End If
                If (InStr(tmpSweep, trimSweep) = 0) Then 'if the stuff we trimmed above doesn't equal our temp string
                  tmpSweep = tmpSweep & trimSweep & "|" 'then add that stuff to our temp string with a delimiter
                End If

         End If
    Next cell
    '===================
    'Write the strings "tmpPort" & "tmpSweep" gathered above into our arrays
    If Len(tmpPort) > 0 Then tmpPort = Left(tmpPort, Len(tmpPort) - 1)
    portArr = Split(tmpPort, "|")
    If Len(tmpSweep) > 0 Then tmpSweep = Left(tmpSweep, Len(tmpSweep) - 1)
    sweepArr = Split(tmpSweep, "|")
    '===================
    'Start filling in cells in column "A" with ports from the port array
    rowDest = rowDest + 1
    colDest = 1
    For i = LBound(portArr) To UBound(portArr)
        Cells(rowDest, 1).Value = portArr(i) 'input the marker value
        rowDest = rowDest + 1 'increment column for markers
    Next  'increment next array item and loop

    '======================================================
    'Here is where I would search for each port's sweep info 
    'and plug it into the appropriate column in Range2
    '======================================================

End Function
```

Comment: Your question is too descriptive. Can you illustrate taking only one sample case that these are inputs and in this manner, processing required on them and final output is in this form. You may get many answers. Suggest edit your question to make it simpler.

Comment: I edited it - not sure how else to ask it.

Comment: Questions here are not about the data or the information they represent but rather how to handle the data. So, I don't understand any of what you show nor should I need to know. To me, the question currently reads as follows: there is a Rang 1 and you want to summarize it to Range 2. As far as I can tell there is not even a programming question here and therefore the question might haven been posted to the wrong website. If not, please post the code you have thus far and where the bug orrurs (you need help with).

Comment: Question is whether I should create a user form with TypeArray items, ask them which items in TypeArray go to which "Port Summary" header, then create a new TypeArray, or just try to make the program reconfigure itself somehow. I don't know how to make sure my TypeArray items is assigned to the right Port Summary headingnor how I use the same array item twice - i.e. use TypeArray item "RLL" to find Range2 heading item "RLL RX" and "RLL TX" before moving on to "RLS"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I muddled through this quite a bit, and this whole section (a function called by my main Sub) still seems very (*very*) clumsy to me - I would definitely appreciate any comments/mail/IM that might make this less wobbly.

The stuff I added to answer my problem is in the section remarked, "New Section".

```
    Function FillSummary()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
    Dim lastrow As Integer
    Dim rowSrc As Integer, colSrc As Integer 'These variables hold the row/column number for getting data
        rowSrc = 1
        colSrc = 1
    Dim rowDest As Integer, colDest As Integer ' These variables hold the row/column number for data entry
        colDest = 1
    Dim rngSrc As Range, rngDest As Range 'These variables hold where the info is copied from/pasted to
    '=======================
    Dim tmpPort As String, tmpSweep As String, trimPort As String, trimSweep As String
    Dim portArr() As String
    Dim sweepArr() As String
    Dim swpHeadArr() As Variant
        swpHeadArr() = Array("DTFWS PK", "DTFL PK", "DTFS PK", "RLL RX PK", "RLL TX PK", _
            "RLS RX PK", "RLS TX PK", "RLWS PK", "RLWS VY", "RLWS TTL") 'Had to change RWS with RLWS to match CSV names
    Dim markColArr() As Variant
        markColArr() = Array(3, 4, 4, 12, 14, 12, 14, 4, 6, 6) 'Tells where to find the value of each test type
    Dim headColRng As Range 'hold the header columns
    Dim swpHead As String 'hold the type of test from the current column's header in the summary area
    Dim arrPos As Integer 'to hold the value of the position of the array item when we look it up
    Dim lookupRng As Range 'to hold the position of our CSV file name find
    '=========================================================

        'Find the last row of sweep data ======================
        With ActiveSheet 'find and set the location of the last row of sweep files
            lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row
        End With
        Set rngSrc = Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(lastrow, 1)) 'Set the range for our source to include all sweep files
        rowDest = lastrow + 2 'make our "rowDest" variable one down from the last row of data
        '======================================================
        'Fill out the fields for our header info
        Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = "Port"
        For i = LBound(swpHeadArr) To UBound(swpHeadArr)
            colDest = colDest + 1 'increment column for sweep headers
            Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = swpHeadArr(i) 'input the sweep header value
        Next  'increment next array item and loop
        '===================
        'Format the header row
        Set headColRng = Range(Cells(rowDest, 1), Cells(rowDest, colDest))
            With headColRng
                .HorizontalAlignment = xlCenter
                .Font.Bold = True
                .Font.Size = 12
                .Interior.ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
                .Interior.TintAndShade = -0.249977111117893
            End With
            '===============
            'Ensure the colum widths for sweeps are "11" (readable)
            Set headColRng = Range(Cells(rowDest, 3), Cells(rowDest, colDest))
            With headColRng
                .EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 11
            End With
        Set headColRng = Range(Cells(rowDest, 2), Cells(rowDest, colDest))

        '======================================================
        'Start populating the arrays with each line/port & sweep type so it can be entered below
        For Each cell In rngSrc
            If Right(cell, 4) = ".csv" Then 'if the cell contains sweep data identified by ".csv" file type
                trimPort = Left(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_") - 1) 'will cut off sweep type & "_" before it
                trimSweep = Mid(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_") + 1, InStr(cell, ".csv") - 1 _
                    - Len(Left(cell, InStrRev(cell, "_")))) 'will cut out everything but the sweep type
                ' ^^^^^^^^^^
                ' basically, take the middle of the cell starting at the last "_",
                ' for a length equal to position in the cell of ".csv", minus 1, minus
                ' the length of the cell contents to the point of the last "_"
                '===========
                    'If (cell <> "") And (InStr(temp, cell) = 0) Then 'empty cell error handling
                    If (InStr(tmpPort, trimPort) = 0) Then 'if the stuff we trimmed above doesn't equal our temp string
                      tmpPort = tmpPort & trimPort & "|" 'then add that stuff to our temp string with a delimiter
                    End If
                    If (InStr(tmpSweep, trimSweep) = 0) Then 'if the stuff we trimmed above doesn't equal our temp string
                      tmpSweep = tmpSweep & trimSweep & "|" 'then add that stuff to our temp string with a delimiter
                    End If

             End If
        Next cell
        '===================
        'Write the strings "tmpPort" & "tmpSweep" gathered above into our arrays
        If Len(tmpPort) > 0 Then tmpPort = Left(tmpPort, Len(tmpPort) - 1)
             portArr = Split(tmpPort, "|")
        If Len(tmpSweep) > 0 Then tmpSweep = Left(tmpSweep, Len(tmpSweep) - 1)
             sweepArr = Split(tmpSweep, "|")
        '===================
        'Start filling in cells in column "A" with ports from the port array
        rowDest = rowDest + 1
        colDest = 1
        For i = LBound(portArr) To UBound(portArr)
            Cells(rowDest, 1).Value = portArr(i) 'input the marker value
            rowDest = rowDest + 1 'increment column for markers
        Next  'increment next array item and loop
        '======================================================

        '======================================================
        'New section ==========================================
    'As a stop-gap, just to get something going, I've implemented the following code to get the summary.
    'However, if the rows of file names are not in alpha order, or one is missing, or anything else goes wrong
    '   this will fail out.
    rowDest = lastrow + 3
    '===================
    ' 1) Cycle through each row of ports
    For i = LBound(portArr) To UBound(portArr)
        colDest = 2
        j = 0
        '===============
        ' 2) Cycle through each column of each of those rows
        For Each cell In headColRng
            '===========
            ' 3) Check active column header row for type of test (string up to the space) & copy that type
            swpHead = Left(cell, InStr(cell, " ") - 1) 'will cut off everything after the type
            '===========
            ' 4) Check sweepArr for the type we copied and return the index ("i")
            arrPos = Application.Match(swpHead, sweepArr, False) - 1
                '=======
                'purely for testing - remove later
                'Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = portArr(i) & "_" & sweepArr(arrPos)
                '=======
                '=======
                ' 5) search the Range1 CSV File names for a match to [current row Port] &"_"& sweepArr(arrPos)
                Set lookupRng = rngSrc.Find(What:=portArr(i) & "_" & sweepArr(arrPos), LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
                If Not lookupRng Is Nothing Then
                    rowSrc = lookupRng.row
                Else
                    MsgBox ("Can't find the sweep for value" _
                        & vbCrLf & portArr(i) & "_" & sweepArr(arrPos) _
                        & vbCrLf & "Please check that this sweep exists")
                    Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = "NoSweep"
                    GoTo NextJ
                End If
            '===========
            ' 6) return the value from the column "#" columns to the right
            ' & plug that value into the current row/column
            If colDest < 11 Then
                Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = Cells(rowSrc, markColArr(j)).Value
                With Cells(rowDest, colDest)
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00_);[Red](0.00)"
                End With
            Else 'unless we're at RLWS "total", then we use a formula
                Cells(rowDest, colDest).Value = (Cells(rowDest, colDest - 1).Value + _
                    Cells(rowDest, colDest - 2).Value) / -2
                With Cells(rowDest, colDest)
                    .NumberFormat = "0.00_);[Red](0.00)"
                End With
            End If
NextJ:             'where a sweep-not-found error takes us
            j = j + 1 'increment array placeholder
            colDest = colDest + 1 'next column
        Next cell
        rowDest = rowDest + 1 'next row
    Next
        '======================================================
        '======================================================
    End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

After loading your data into the Range1 and Range2 you have done already, you can use Vlookup to return the Marker information from Range1. E.g. if you were to put this in cell B40 in your example:

```
=VLOOKUP($A40 & "_" & LEFT(B$39,FIND(" ",B$39)-1) & ".csv", $A$18:$M$37, 3, FALSE)
```

The third argument in VLookup is the column, so in this case would return the value from the 3rd column: Marker 1 dBm.
Your step 4 is not specific, but you can change the third argument to suit which column you want the data from.

Comment: This would work, except that Range2 is created using the code I have so far - doesn't exist before that. I'm not savvy enough to know how to put in that VLOOKUP into the cells I need using code.

Comment: Hi @JGR , this is how to add this formula using VBA: `range("B40:K45").FormulaR1C1 = "=VLOOKUP(RC1 & ""_"" & LEFT(R39C,FIND("" "",R39C)-1) & "".csv"", R18C1:R37C13, 3, FALSE)"` . Or, alternatively if you want to add the value cell by cell instead of a formula, use vlookup like this, with the same argument inputs: `range("B40").Value = worksheetfunction.VLookup(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)`

Comment: This will come in handy in the next sheet that I have to create after finalizing the summary info - thank you.